# Test wrapping cutting words in half on my WP site

Tags: css, text

How do I solve my problem with text wrapping in my columns on: http://socialeer.dk/om-os/

I would like to have the text wrapping happen and dividing the words correctly (please note that the text is in Danish)

Comment: not a wordpress question, it can and should be done with css, using the break-word functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Your headings (h1, h2, etc) have the css property `word-break: break-all;` applied to them. Removing this property in Firebug provides the correct line breaks. You could override this in your child theme CSS.